# NInject 3 Conventions NInject attribute not getting injected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ninject, ninject-extensions

For a class with below construct, constructor injection works great but not property. What else do i need to add to the conventions to make `Inject` attribute work

```
public partial class Repo
{
     [Inject] 
     public ILogger Logger{get;set;}
}
```

**Bindings in NInjectWebCommon.cs**

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            //Dispose all resource after the requests ends
            kernel.Bind(x => x.FromAssembliesMatching("*").SelectAllClasses().BindAllInterface().Configure(scope=>scope.InRequestScope()));

        }
```

Comment: Ninject is probably not able to create that logger. Have you tried it with some plain object? Are you using logging extension for Ninject?

Comment: @mipe34 ILogger is a Interface i had developed no logging extension. What do i do to Inject the  Interface then?

Comment: That should work. Which component is requesting the repo? And why is it partial?

Comment: @DanielMarbach thanks for replying. It's been long time & no answers. Partial is there because one part of the file is auto-generated by the  EntityFramework Model Designer i need to access the `Logger` in the partial class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm asuming that the repository class is instantiated by entity framework somehow. So if you are not requesting the repo isntance with ninject you need to build up the existing instance with ninject. That can be done with the `Inject` method on the kernel.

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
var repo = new Repo();
kernel.Inject(repo);
```

Comment: where `var Kernel = new StandardKernel()` ? because Kernel is not static global variable